# First few GRPC requests time out on Heroku when using MassTransit

Tags: docker, heroku, masstransit

I have two MassTransit buses using GRPC which are hosted by two different .net core WebApplications and those applications run in same process which runs inside docker container and this container is deployed to heroku.

There is REST API endpoint exposed to the public that just sends GRPC request and receives response:

```
app.MapPost("test-grpc", async () =>
{
    using var scope = app1.Services.CreateScope();
    var bus = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IGrpcBus>();
    var client = bus.CreateRequestClient<GrpcMessage>();
    var response = await client.GetResponse<GrpcResponse>(new GrpcMessage() { Value = "request_123" });
    return response.Message.ResponseValue;
});
```

When application is started on heroku in logs I can see following entries:

```bash
Jan 26 16:37:42  [INF APP_2] gRPC Connect: http://127.0.0.1:19001/ (MassTransit) {"Module":"METRICS","SourceContext":"MassTransit","Level":"Information","Timestamp":"2024-01-26T15:37:42.4294311+00:00"}
Jan 26 16:37:42  [INF APP_1] gRPC Connect: http://127.0.0.1:19000/ (MassTransit) {"Module":"JIRA","SourceContext":"MassTransit","Level":"Information","Timestamp":"2024-01-26T15:37:42.4573197+00:00"}
Jan 26 16:37:43  [INF APP_1] gRPC Connected: http://127.0.0.1:19000/ (MassTransit) {"Module":"JIRA","SourceContext":"MassTransit","Level":"Information","Timestamp":"2024-01-26T15:37:43.1110933+00:00"}
Jan 26 16:37:43  [INF APP_2] gRPC Connected: http://127.0.0.1:19001/ (MassTransit) {"Module":"METRICS","SourceContext":"MassTransit","Level":"Information","Timestamp":"2024-01-26T15:37:43.1185939+00:00"}
Jan 26 16:37:43  [INF APP_2] Bus started: http://127.0.0.1:19000/ (MassTransit) {"Module":"METRICS","SourceContext":"MassTransit","Level":"Information","Timestamp":"2024-01-26T15:37:43.1625409+00:00"}
Jan 26 16:37:43  [INF APP_1] Bus started: http://127.0.0.1:19001/ (MassTransit) {"Module":"JIRA","SourceContext":"MassTransit","Level":"Information","Timestamp":"2024-01-26T15:37:43.1641062+00:00"}
```

So it looks like both apps "see" each other (APP_1 bound to port 19001 connects to APP_2 bound to port 19000).

Now when I make requests to `POST <heroku_app_external_address>/test-grpc` first 2-3 (it varies) requests always time out:

```bash
MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException: 
Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: 02000000-e137-5299-37e7-08dc1e865064\n   
at MassTransit.Clients.ResponseHandlerConnectHandle`1.GetTask() in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/ResponseHandlerConnectHandle.cs:line 58\n   
at MassTransit.Clients.RequestClient`1.GetResponseInternal[T](SendRequestCallback request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestTimeout timeout, RequestPipeConfiguratorCallback`1 callback) in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/RequestClient.cs:line 195\n   
at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<<Main>$>b__4>d.MoveNext() in /app/src/Gateway/Gateway.Host/Program.cs:line 69\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<ExecuteTaskOfString>g__ExecuteAwaited|113_0(Task`1 task, HttpContext httpContext)\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

After those 2-3 requests fail it starts working successfully making GRPC requests between apps. After first request succeeds it works forever until process (heroku dyno) is restarted. It does not matter if I start making requests just after app has started or 5 minutes later - first 2-3 requests always time out.

Locally when running in docker on my computer it always work, could not reproduce this issue.

One note: I am aware how heroku dynos work, and what I do is totally legit as per heroku docs:

```
Individual processes within a dyno can bind to any address or port they want and communicate among them using e.g. standard TCP
```

So within single dyno (container) it's allowed that single process listen on many ports and communicates over those ports via TCP. And it works, except those first 2-3 requests

Here is how mass transit is configured (same for both apps just with different ports):

```
services.AddMassTransit<IGrpcBus>(cfg =>
{
    cfg.UsingGrpc((context, grpcCfg) =>
    {
        grpcCfg.Host(h =>
        {
            h.Host = "127.0.0.1";
            h.Port = 19001;

            h.AddServer(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:19000"));
        });

        grpcCfg.AutoStart = true;

        grpcCfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);

    });
});
```

I suspect that this has something to do with this issue [envoy: grpc-web takes a few requests until it no longer times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76650884/envoy-grpc-web-takes-a-few-requests-until-it-no-longer-times-out) - someone had same problem with GRPC (first few requests failing) but in different environment - the issue was that in some environments GRPC initial connection sometimes take longer than configured maximum initial connection timeout and the solution was to increate "connect-timeout" for GRPC.

However I couldn't find option in MassTransit to configure "connect-timeout" for GRPC transport and also this is weird that despite I am configuring GRPC with AutoStart = true, under the hood it looks like GRPC connection is not established until first requests are made (on the other hand logs say gRPC Connected: http://127.0.0.1:19000/ - even if I set AutoStart = false which is also weird).

Another thing is that I could not find a way to wait until bus is healthy as in this mass transit example https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Grpc/blob/master/WorkerNode/ClaimSubmissionService.cs#L30, because IGrpcBus is second bus I am registering in in both apps(the first one is MassTransit + RabbitMQ) and for second bus IBusControl is not registered in DI container as it states in MassTransit docs. But not sure if it's necessary to wait for bus to be healthy or not.

Using MassTransit / MassTransit.Grpc `8.1.3` and `net7.0`.

Comment: Just FYI, the MassTransit gRPC transport was just deprecated and will no longer be updated.

Comment: Thanks for info, I did not know about list of deprecated packages. Makes sense to me since GRPC is for different purposes than MassTransit in general, though it was really nice and easy to use GRPC with MassTransit.